# Change color to shape for making a color gradient to Processing

Tags: java, processing

I have the following code in processing and I want to add the ability to create a color gradient between recurrent colors. Depending on how many shapes I have, the corresponding values ​​of `0-255` will be shared. For example, if I have five parallel (concentric) shapes, then I will have the following values ​​`0-51-102-153-204-255`. The beginning and the end will always be `0` and `255` (white and black).

```
float step = 0.50; // 0.5 == 50%
float hearts = 4; // heart count

void setup(){
    size(800, 800);
    stroke(0, 255, 0);
    noFill();
}

void draw(){
    background(255);
    translate(400, 400);
    for(int i = 0; i < hearts; i++) {
      for(int heart = 1; heart<= 256; heart+=heart){
        fill(0,0,0,100);
      }
        float scale = 1 + i * step;
        pushMatrix();
        scale(scale);
        strokeWeight(1.0 / scale);
        heart();
        popMatrix();
    }
    saveFrame("line-######.png");
}

void heart(){
    beginShape();
    vertex(0, 75);
    vertex(-50, 0);
    vertex(-25, -75);
    vertex(0, -50);
    vertex(25, -75);
    vertex(50, 0);
    endShape(CLOSE);
}
```

[image]

Comment: So, what is the question?

Comment: Γεια σου Πέτρο.
How I customize my code to have color gradient correctly. In my code I can't have the correct color gradient for 0 to 255 or opposite.

Comment: Χαίρεται! It would be nice to clearly form the question next time, in your question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you are drawing first the smallest one, then the next larger, then the next until you draw the largest. Thus even if you do get the colours correctly, the largest one will cover all the rest, and you will have to rely on transparency (and you don't have to). Thus, to change your code as little as possible instead of

```
for(int i = 0; i < hearts; i++) {
```

inverse it like this:

```
for(int i = int(hearts-1); i >= 0; i--) {
```

Second, doing this:

```
for(int heart = 1; heart<= 256; heart+=heart){
   fill(0,0,0,100);
}
```

does the same command (`fill(0,0,0,100);`) 256 times, and ends with the same result at the `}`, and that result is that you will fill each shape with the same FULLY BLACK semi-transparent colour: (0,0,0,100).

The same effect would be achieved if you just replaced the whole for with this:

```
fill(0,0,0,100);
```

The fact that you somehow reach a gradient effect is thanks to the layers of (additive) transparency, and not thanks to properly calculating each colour of each layer. To do that, you need to do something like this:

```
fill((i/(hearts-1))*255);
```

What would happen here is, as the for loop decreases `i` until it reaches 0 the `(i/(hearts-1))*255` number changes accordingly sort of like this:

```
Let's suppose hearts = 4 as you have here... 
Remember, i in the new for loop starts from i = hearts-1 = 3

 i  |  (i/(hearts-1))*255
--------------------------
 3  |  (3/(  4   -1))*255  =  255 (white)
 2  |  (2/(  4   -1))*255  ~  170 (light gray)
 1  |  (1/(  4   -1))*255  ~  85  (dark gray)
 0  |  (0/(  4   -1))*255  =  0   (black)
```

There is no transparency here, so you need to fix the aforementioned for loop to see the effect.

The whole draw() method should look like this:

```
void draw() {
  background(255);
  translate(400, 400);
  for (int i = int(hearts-1); i >= 0; i--) {
    fill((i/(hearts-1))*255);
    float scale = 1 + i * step;
    pushMatrix();
    scale(scale);
    strokeWeight(1.0 / scale);
    heart();
    popMatrix();
  }
  saveFrame("line-######.png");
}
```

Comment: First of all thank you for your answer.
Correct me, but I think the last "shape" it is not white, isn't it?

Comment: Well, if you just copy pasted the draw code as it is pasted at the end not, because I made a small mistake... If you followed the things I said at the beginning you would get the white shape... Nevertheless I fixed it there too!